# KnockoutObservable<number> returns string when bound to an input in typescript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I use Knockout version 3.2.0 and its [definitelyTyped](https://www.nuget.org/packages/knockout.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/) definitions from nuget:

I have a property bound to an input (type number) with value binding, the property definition is:

```
export class SomeClass {
    myProp: KnockoutObservable<number>;

   constructor() {
       myProp = ko.observable(0);
   }
}
```

Now, fiddling with console, when the class is initialized the property returns 0 when called. However, after I change the value in the input, the property starts to return string, e.g. if I change it to 2, the returned value is "2". This is obviously a problem when adding two such properties together.

```
var x = myinstance.myProp() + myinstance.myProp();
```

The result is not 4, as you would expect it to be, the result is actually "22", the concatenation.

Is there any reasonable solution? Is it a bug in knockout or a documented behaviour?

Comment: Whoever corrected the article, please see http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/behaviour, behaviour is a correct british english spelling!

Comment: Here's a typed observable implemented in coco (just compile it to javascript).  It's got a lot of extra stuff, sorry I don't have much time to unpack it for you.  That's why I'm just posting as a comment: https://github.com/milimetric/limn/blob/master/src/util/knockout/typed-observable.co

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've bound a string value to numeric type and expect automatic type conversion to happen during binding. This won't work because first and foremost KnockoutJS is a Javascript framework which knows nothing about Typescript's Type System.

You could either make the property a writeable-computed observable or introduce a read-only computed observable that simply runs the current value of "myProp" through parseInt().

Comment: well I would at least expect that typescript would throw a runtime error that a string is returned from a number type, because this basically makes the type checking completely useless...On the other hand, this could really be quite hard and inefficient to achieve

Comment: there is no such thing as typescript runtime  error. All the typescript happens in compile time

Comment: @Santhos There is NO Typescript runtime. Typescript is all compiler "magic".

Comment: That is why I say it would be hard to achieve. You would need to generate a lot more code and throw just the generic Error. I know that Typescript is compiled to javascript "on build".

Comment: @Santhos I totally agree with you but we've got to work with what we've got :)

Comment: Anyway, this should probably be somehow natively solved in the knockout library itself. I belive it causes problems not only to typescript users, it is only more confusing in typescript to see number type returned as string :)

Comment: @Santhos This problem can't be solved by KnockoutJS because Javascript is not statically typed. And even though it is possible to determine if a variable is a number or a string _after_ it has been a assigned a value, this would not work for uninitialized properties.

Comment: @Santhos this is by design in knocout because there is no notions of types in it. However it is a common problem and there is a common pattern exists to solve it: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html#live-example-1-forcing-input-to-be-numeric

Comment: @nemesv The extender really helped me. I had to tweak it a bit to fit my needs. I mean, it is actually the solution I was looking for. You should definitely post it as a regular answer, I would mark it as the right one.